# Java clipboard information with in application

Tags: java

From Eclipse I am running one java application, in that application using java Clipboard.
I want clipboard information to be considered only with in that application, if I copy on notepad then it should not copy clipboard information because of some security reasons.
Is this possible ? Can anybody suggest ? 
Please let me know if anybody need more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify flavours which are unique to your app, so that other apps are not likely to pick up the data.

Refer: https://www.javaworld.com/article/2077562/core-java/java-tip-61--cut--copy--and-paste-in-java.html

Also: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/dataflavor.html

Comment: Ok sure, I will try this. Thank you.